# Could you explain what happens when you use a bitwise & operator between two hexdecimal strands?

Tags: java, bit-manipulation

I got this from the Java tutorial and I'm lost, I just don't understand what happens when you use the & operator

```
class BitDemo {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int bitmask = 0x000F;
    int val = 0x2222;
    // prints "2"
    System.out.println(val & bitmask);
}
}
```

How would I make the the two ints (bitmask and val) display 14?
I have no concept as to how you manipulate them to make numbers.

Comment: This is anding operation between (0010001000100010 and 0000000000001111) so result is (0000000000000010 = 2), look at this http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation#AND

Comment: Is the questions about the & operator or about how to display 14?

Comment: There are 0x3e6b41437d93 ways to take a pair of `int`'s `(x, y)` such that `(x & y) == 14`, including the trivial `(-1, 14)` and `(14, -1)` (see [here](http://haroldbot.cloudapp.net/?q=solve%20x%26y%3D14))

Answer (score 7):

& is the [bitwise AND](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation#AND) operator.

Let's put the truth table of this operator for two variables :

```
p   q   p & q
0   0     0
0   1     0
1   0     0
1   1     1
```

Your values in binary are equals to (you can use [`Integer.toBinaryString(int i)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#toBinaryString%28int%29)):

```
00000000001111
10001000100010
```

Applying the & yields in :

```
   00000000001111
&  10001000100010
__________________
   00000000000010
```

which is equals to 2.

---

> How would I make the the two ints (bitmask and val) display 14?

Just put your mask as `0xFFFF` (only '1') and val as 14 (`0x000E` in hexadecimal).

```
int bitmask = 0xFFFF;
int val = 0x000E;
```

This is one possible solution.

Answer (score 5):

& is the bitwise AND operator.

```
a      0x000F = 0000 0000 0000 1111
b      0x2222 = 0010 0010 0010 0010

-----------------------------------
a & b         = 0000 0000 0000 0010 = 2
```

And to get 14, try `0x000F & 0x000E`.

Answer (score 0):

`&` is [Bitwise](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation) AND operator

```
int a = 4;
int b = 7;
System.out.println(a & b); // prints 4

meaning in an 32 bit system
00000000 00000000 00000000 00000100
00000000 00000000 00000000 00000111
===================================
00000000 00000000 00000000 00000100
```